# Any alternate method to find probability of function of two random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variables such that $X\sim U(0,2)$ and $Y\sim U(1,3)$. Then $P(X<Y)$ equals

I can do this question using transformation $U=X/Y$ ,$V=Y$ as $P(\frac{X}{Y}<1)$is there any other method to do this without using this transformation. The solution I got is 7/8. This question was asked in a test, where I am supposed to do it fast and this method little tedious. Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$. Now:

$\begin{eqnarray}
P(X<Y)&=&1-P(Y \le X)\\
&=&1-\int_1^2\int_1^xf_X(x)f_Y(y)dydx\\
&=&1-\frac{1}{8}\\
&=&\frac{7}{8}
\end{eqnarray}$

Note that, if you don't want to solve the integral, drawing a picture you will note that $P(Y \le X)$ is the area of the triangle with vertices $(1,1)$, $(2,1)$ and $(2,2)$ over the area of rectangle $[0,2]\times[1,3]$: $\frac{1/2}{2\times 2}=1/8$